# Pig map reduce job to place values within proper range

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a list of values as one data source and a second dataset which contains ranges tied to a value.

```
Dataset 1:
3
4
6
20
25
38

Dataset 2:
1|3|A
4|10|B
11|20|C
21|30|D
31|31|E
32|38|F
39|40|G

Result:
3,A
4,B
6,B
20,C
25,D
38,F
```

I'd like to create some type of "JOIN" to tie the value in dataset 1 to the character in Dataset 2.

Comment: How large (approximately) might each dataset be?

Comment: Not sure, my guess is that dataset 1 would be more likely to be larger. The second dataset is likely to be a smaller number of lines 200k - 500k entries. If there is a benefit to assuming the one is larger than the other, I'd be curious to see both implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If either of Donald Miner's suggestions work fast enough for you I'd just do those, but to make it faster, if DataSet 2 only has 250K-500K entries you should be able to fit the entire thing into memory. Therefore you could: write a udf that stores DataSet 2 into memory (see `getCacheFiles` for how to store a hdfs file into the DistributedCache. Then write an `EvalFunc` that takes a single item of DataSet A, binary searches for it's location in DataSet 2, and returns the answer you want.

```
ANSWER = FOREACH DATASET1 GENERATE myBinarySearchUdf(number) 
   as myResult:Tuple(originalNumber:int, dataSet2Id:chararray);
```

Comment: Cool. i didn't know you could do this in Pig (but it doesn't surprise me). Where in the code can you load the data set into memory so that it doesn't reload the data set every UDF call?

Comment: There's no initialize function that gets called on the backend, so in the O'Reilly book on pig they say the only good way to do it, is to lazy load the data set into memory in the exec function with something like if(dataSet == null) { dataSet = initializeDataSet() }. That way it gets loaded on first call only.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that the way MapReduce does joins requires keys to match up exactly and it buckets things randomly in the paritioner (by default). There are probably a bunch of tricky ways to do this with Java MapReduce. The two most straightforward I can think of in Pig are below. Not sure which would be faster... it depends on the nature of the data.

---

Use cross product:

```
C = CROSS A, B;
D = FILTER C BY $1 >= $2 AND $1 <= $3;
```

This can be slow! But it gets the job done!

---

Blow up the range, then do a join

```
B2 = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(explode_range_udf($1, $2, $3));
C = JOIN A by $1, B2 by $1;
```

This is where you write a udf called `explode_range_udf` that takes in the three values and returns a bag of tuples that contain each possible element in the range. For example:

```
explode_range_udf(1,3,A)   ->   {(1,A),(2,A),(3,A)}
```

`FLATTEN` creates on record per item in the bag.